# Logical NaN Error in my React Typescript counter for win percentage

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, nan

I am making a simple Typescript counter to track my win percentage in my Legends of Runeterra games I play. I can't figure out why when I increment a win or a loss I get NaN as my win percentage. The logic seems fine (obviously you can't decrement right now, that's a problem for later), I just want to focus on fixing the NaN error for now.

Here's my counter component:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'

// add a ? after the type name if you want any one of these to be optional, ex: wins?
const Counter: React.FC<{
  initialGamesPlayed: number
  initialWins: number
  initialLosses: number
  initialWinPercentage: number
  initialDeckName: string
}> = ({
  initialDeckName,
  initialWinPercentage,
  initialWins,
  initialLosses,
  initialGamesPlayed,
}) => {
  const [deckName, setDeckName] = useState(initialDeckName)
  const [wins, setWins] = useState(initialWins)
  const [losses, setLosses] = useState(initialLosses)
  const [totalGames, setTotalGames] = useState(initialGamesPlayed)
  const [winPercentage, setWinPercentage] = useState(initialWinPercentage)

  const incrementWins = () => {
    setWins(wins + 1)
    winPercentageCalc()
    console.log(winPercentage)
  }
  const decrementWins = () => {
    if (wins > 0) setWins(wins - 1)
    winPercentageCalc()
  }
  const incrementLosses = () => {
    setLosses(losses + 1)
    winPercentageCalc()
    console.log(winPercentage)
  }
  const decrementLosses = () => {
    if (losses > 0) setLosses(losses - 1)
    winPercentageCalc()
  }
  const winPercentageCalc = () => {
    setTotalGames(wins + losses)
    setWinPercentage((wins / totalGames) * 100)
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <p>Deck Name: </p>
      <p>wins: {wins} </p>
      <button onClick={incrementWins}>+</button>
      <button onClick={decrementWins}>-</button>
      <p>losses: {losses}</p>
      <button onClick={incrementLosses}>+</button>
      <button onClick={decrementLosses}>-</button>
      <p>Win Percentage: {winPercentage} % </p>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Counter
```

Thanks for taking a look!

Comment: is `totalGames` ever 0? maybe you have a divide by 0 error

Comment: You should perhaps protect from division by 0. If totalGames === 0 then setWinPercentage(0).

Comment: What i think happen is thatstate updates are not immediate (synchronous) with react. So when you call setWinPercentage, the total isn't updated yet, it's still 0 and you end up dividing by 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `setWins, setLosses, setTotalGames and setWinPercentage` are all asynchronous functions. So the first time your call `winPercentageCalc`, this is what happens:

```
const winPercentageCalc = () => {
    setTotalGames(wins + losses) // This is asynchronous, so...
    setWinPercentage((wins / totalGames) * 100) // totalGames = 0 => NaN
}
```

When you divide wins by totalGames, totalGames has not been updated so you divide by 0 which gives NaN (Not a Number) as a result